# Does resetting an Apple ID remove the data from all devices logged in with that ID?

Tags: iphone, password

I forgot the passcode of my 2nd iPhone and now it's permanently disabled. If I reset it with iTunes will it also remove the data of the Apple ID from the first device which is logged in with that ID?

Comment: Are you asking about resetting an Apple ID or the passcode of a phone?

Answer (score 1):

I gather the situation is that you have a primary iPhone and a secondary iPhone that are both logged in with the same AppleID and thus have some of the same data on them synced via iCloud.

Due to the forgotten pass code, you're thinking of erasing all contents on the secondary iPhone and restoring it with a blank iOS installation.

In that case, the data on your primary iPhone is not erased. Data stored in iCloud will not be erased either.

Comment: You sure this will work if sync is enabled?

Comment: I’m sure the data in iCloud isn’t erased when you erase the contents on the phone, yes.

Comment: Okay, nice!! ;)